# Skip travis build if an unimportant file changed

Tags: travis-ci

I use continuous integration with [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) to run my unit tests on every commit. However, sometimes all I want to do is edit the README. Is there a way to skip Travis builds if all the changes are restricted to a whitelisted set of files?

Comment: you mean, tell Travis to not run the test on a specific file??

Comment: I mean to tell Travis not to run if all the changes in the last commit were restricted to that file. As it is, Travis often wastes time checking code when all I changed was the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no way to directly make Travis dynamically determine, based only on the type of file that has been changed, if it should run a build.

However, Travis will [ignore any commit](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#skipping-a-build) with `[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]` in the commit message.

Perhaps you could use a [git hook](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks) (say [`prepare-commit-msg`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) or similar) to append `[ci-skip]` to the commit message when only `.md` files have been modified.

In the git hook, you could detect this scenario with a command like `git diff --exit-code --name-only -- . ':(exclude)*.md'`.

In action:

```
$ git diff --name-only
README.md
$ git diff --exit-code --name-only -- . ':(exclude)*.md'
$ echo $?
0
```

If any non `*.md` files have been changed, the command will return `1`, otherwise `0`.